# Why need Collector.toList() in the aggregate operation?

Tags: java, aggregate

Can someone explain why we need the last expression Collectors.toList() in the first aggregate operation but not in the second and the third?

```
Map<Person.Sex, List<String>> namesByGender =
  roster
     .stream()
     .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Person::getGender,
            Collectors.mapping(
               Person::getName,
               Collectors.toList()))); // why need toList here?

Map<Person.Sex, Integer> totalAgeByGender =
   roster
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.groupingBy(
           Person::getGender,
           Collectors.reducing(
              0,
              Person::getAge,
              Integer::sum)));

Map<Person.Sex, List<Person>> byGender =
  roster
   .stream()
   .collect(
      Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getGender)); //without toList()
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Have you looked at the signatures of the functions?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. There are two completely different downstream collectors used in these two grouping by examples. The first performs a map operation, the second a reduction operation.

Comment: I see both aggregate return Map instances, but one has toList, the other does not. So, that is why I want to know what is the function of toList in the first aggregate operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `groupingBy` collector creates entries in a `Map`. A `Map` contains Key-Value Pairs, so we say it's a `Map<K,V>`. In order to group into a map, we need a method that determines the key, and we need a method that collects the value.

In the second case, the collection of the value is to sum the values up by gender - total age by gender. The `Map` is of type `Map<Person.Sex, *Integer*>`. This means that the key to the map is the gender, and the value stored for the key is the total age for that gender. So the grouping needs to be by `Person.Sex` and the collection is by *sum*, which means the collection turns *`int`* values into *`Integer`* values by summing them up using the *`Integer.sum()`* method on the return values of `Person.getAge()`.

In the first case, the collection of the value is to list all names by gender. The `Map` is of type `Map<Person.Sex, *List<String>*>`. This means that the key to the map is the gender, and the value stored for the key is a *`List` of `String`s (names)*. So the grouping needs to be by `Person.Sex` and the collection is by *listing the names*, which means the collection turns *`String`* values into *`List<String>`* values by collecting them into a list using a corresponding collector returned by *`Collectors.toList()`*.

Comment: I just update the third aggregate operation, and my confusion actually comes from it. Now, it does not have any Collectors.toList() but it still collect values into lists. So why the first still need toList()?

Comment: In the first case, the output type *`String`* is different from the input type *`Person`*, so additional details need to be specified in order to tell how to come from `Person` to `String`. In the third case, the output type *`Person`* is identical to the input type *`Person`*, so the default collector used by the simple `groupingBy` method variant works (which implies `toList()`, but it's calling it on its own behalf, no explicit call required).